# What are these weird noises coming from my computer, and how do I fix it?

Tags: laptop, windows-10, noise

Laptop producing weird noises from inside, sounds electrical.  This can be reproduced simply by scrolling up and down using an external mouse or the trackpad, or simply typing on the keyboard.

Laptop is an Msi PE60 with a GTX 960m and an i7-6700hq CPU.

Running windows 10.

What could be causing this noise, what is the noise, and how would I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to take a sound clip of the noise using a mobile phone or similar and upload it so that we can try and figure this out with you?

More often that not, based on what you have described - this will be a loose wire/cable somewhere inside the laptop.  If a cable has come loose and is somewhere near your laptop speaker and the signals going down the wire are interfering with the speaker itself.

To fix this, you will normally need to dismantle the laptop (at least partly) and make sure that all wires are seated correctly and are away from the speakers within your laptop.  Normally, you will see a small plastic clip where the cables should be running.